# Dependency Injection too late

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javafx-2

I am using JavaFX 2 in conjunction with the Spring Framework, however the injection happens to late. My Controller is instanciated by the FXML-Loader, the Spring injection for member variables of this Controller works, but it works only too late, this means that in (1) injection yet didn't happen and in (2) injection did happen:

```
public class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    @Autowired
    public StatusBarController statusbarController;

    // Implementing Initializable Interface no longer required according to
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm:
    private void initialize() {
        BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane)getView();        
        borderPane.setBottom(statusbarController.getView()); // (1) null exception!
    }

    // Linked to a button in the view
    public void sayHello() {
        BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane)getView();        
        borderPane.setBottom(statusbarController.getView()); // (2) works!
    }
}
```

Any way to let Spring inject `statusbarController` in an earlier state? I can't let the user have to click a button to load my GUI ;-)

My AppFactory is this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppFactory 
{
    @Bean
    public MainController mainController() throws IOException
    {
        return (MainController) loadController("/main.fxml");
    }

    protected Object loadController(String url) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream fxmlStream = null;
        try
        {
            fxmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Node view = (Node) loader.load(fxmlStream);
            AbstractController controller = (AbstractController) loader.getController();
            controller.setView(view);
            return controller;            
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fxmlStream != null)
            {
                fxmlStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a ControllerFactory on the FXMLLoader so that you are in charge of creating the controller instance.

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the problem! For the records: There's an example e.g. here http://koenserneels.blogspot.de/2012/11/javafx-2-with-spring.html (search for setcontrollerfactory)